# How do i use DejaVu Fonts in android

Tags: android

I want to develop an application android that can display/support arab font by using android 1.5, and I found a DejaVu font but how can I use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For using Custom font's use this code,

```
TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custom_font);  
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "YourFontNamer.rtf");  
txt.setTypeface(font);
```

if you need more refer this blog http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/customize-android-fonts/

Comment: and shoul I put "MyFont.ttf" inside the project android?

Comment: Nope, you put your font in assets folder.

Comment: this font greatly supports Unicode, however, it seems it does not look beautiful